# How to determine if an argument was passed with a gRPC call or not?

Tags: python, grpc-python

**Question**: When parsing a gRPC call's request in my gRPC endpoint, how can I make use of a certain `request.<attribute>` *only* if it was explicitly passed with the gRPC call?

---

I have this in my .proto:

```proto
message Object {
    bool enabled = 1;
}
```

I have this as my endpoint:

```py
class CRUDService(CRUDServicer):
    @staticmethod
    def Create(request: Object_pb2.CreateReq, context) -> Object_pb2.CreateResp:

        options = {}

        if request.enabled:
            options["enabled"] = request.enabled

        obj = create_obj(options)
        
        return Object_pb2.CreateResp(serialized_obj=serialize(obj))
```

However, the if-condition does not check if `enabled` was passed with the call or not. It turns out `enabled` is *always* accessible on the `request` object. And with the snippet above, I will make it impossible to set `options = {"enabled": False}`, which I want to be able to do.

So, when querying `request.enabled`, I will get one of:

1. The default value, explicitly passed with the call
2. The default value, not passed with the call
3. The non-default value, explicitly passed with the call

To further illustrate the problem, imagine setting up an `Update` endpoint (for the U in CRUD). Then I only want to update with whatever request fields were actually passed with the gRPC call - and not just update with a default value of something which was not even passed with the call.

Comment: @Marat can you expand on what you mean by that?

Comment: Sorry, used C++ way of checking if a field is present. It should be `request.HasField('enabled')` in Python

Comment: actually, the main problem: `enabled` should be declared as optional in the protobuf. Sorry, missed it the first time

Comment: @Marat I just tried your suggestion and I got `Failed with Error: Can't test non-optional, non-submessage field "CreateReq.enabled" for presence in proto3.`. But I assume what you are saying about declaring `optional` in the .proto could solve that - and enable the user of `.HasField`?

Comment: @Marat - you were right! If you create a formal answer, I will upvote/accept. Many, many thanks for this.